# How to get object form store by id Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to get an object from the store by id from the route. Id depends on the route, and i get it properly. Something wrong with the function. Maybe i should use filter function?

```
    props: ['id'], // my props
    computed: { // computed property
      product () { // function name
        const id = this.id; // getting id
        return this.$store.getters.productById(id) // getting object from store
      }
    }

    state: { // state 
      products: [ //products array
        {
          id: 1, // id
          title: 'Lenovo Legion Y520', // title
          vendor: 'Lenovo', // vendor
          color: 'black', // color
          material: 'metal/plastic', // material
    },
    {
          id: 2, // id
          title: 'Asus FX503VD', // title
          vendor: 'Asus', // vendor
          color: 'white', // color
          material: 'plastic', //plastic
    },
    {
          id: 3, // id
          title: 'ASUS TUF Gaming FX504GD', // title
          vendor: 'Asus', // vendor
          color: 'black', // color
          material: 'metal/plastic' //material
      }
    ]

    getters: { // getters
      productById (state) { // function
      return productId => { // product by id
        return state.products.find(product => product.id === productId)
        }
      }
    }

// route settings
{
  path: '/product/:id', // route path
  props: true, //enabled props
  name: 'product', // route name
  component: Product // component name
}

// main js importing plugins and Vue

import router from './router' // import router
import store from './store' // import store
import Vuetify from 'vuetify' // import vuetify

Vue.use(Vuetify); // use vuetify plugin

Vue.config.productionTip = false; // false

new Vue({ // new class instance
  el: '#app', // el name
  router, // enabled routing
  store, // enabled store
  components: { App }, // component name
  template: '<App/>' // template name
});
```

Maybe i am passing id not an appropriate way, this.$store.getters.productById(id)? I don't have ideas how can i deal with it

Comment: Instead of passing parameters, i can recommend you to, take a look into `vuex-router-sync` plugin. It automatically inject `route` object into your state. By doing this, you don't need to set extra prop, you don't need to pass your id to getter. Just simply use `state.products.find(product => product.id === state.route.params.id)` in your getter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe don't use the [strict equality comparison](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-strict-equality-comparison) inside your `productById` getter.

If you debbug inside the function, you can see:

```
console.log(typeof product.id) #=> number
console.log(typeof productId)  #=> string
```

Try with `product.id == productId` instead of `product.id === productId`

Answer (score 2):

`State` and `getters` - it are different objects. You have to divide them. Put the closing bracket after `"]"`